# Ability to make API calls out of Wordpress as well as executing SQL?

Tags: plugins, rest-api

I'm pretty new to Wordpress, so I'm risking some downvotes here... but, I'm curious, are there any recommended plug-ins that have the ability to make REST API calls?  I have access to a third party API, and I need to be able to execute REST calls to that API.  For simplicity's sake, consider this use case: executing an HTTPGET call to the API to retrieve content to display on the page.

Additionally, are there any plug-ins capable of executing SQL against a non-Wordpress database?  Similar use case as above - I need to be able to execute SQL to populate a database hosted by GoDaddy from the data retrieved from the API call above.

Comment: Can't think of anything off-hand, I'd code that kind of thing manually using curl requests & mysql.

Comment: @admcfajn thanks for the reply!  Unfortunately I'm a .NET person (as opposed to PHP) so I'd feel more comfortable using the UI/plug-ins.  One of the downfalls of not being super versed in PHP unfortunately. :(

Comment: Wish I could help more, making a plugin is pretty simple, you can find a really barebones example in the hello-dolly plugin that ships with WordPress (The declarations in the comment-section at the top of the file are imporant). Aside from that, you'd use [WordPress HTTP API](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-guide-to-the-wordpress-http-api-the-basics--wp-25125) or [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to ping the api, or `file_get_contents()`... & then read [Creating Tables with Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins) to get started with that.

Comment: Do you mean SQL Server, not MySql?

Comment: @admcfajn Yes, SQL Server.  And thanks for the information too, very helpful.